# Non-Elected, Rejected and Objected claims, and reviving the abandoned patent

Tags: claims, abandoned-patent, assignee, revive

I followed my patent application after 3 years and found that it is abandoned. The abandonment report mentioned that patent has been abandoned because "No reply has been received". The final claim report says that out of 21 claims 4 non-elected, 9 rejected, and 8 objected. 
The assignee is my previous employer and after receiving Index of Claims they didn't reply, which caused the abandonment of patent.
 Legally speaking, is it possible to revoke/revive the abandoned patent with the current employer as a new assignee?

 Is there any difference between rejected and abandoned patent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abandoned Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/20470/abandoned-patents) Patents do not go abandoned due to not responding to index of claims. No response is needed. It would be abandoned due to non-response to objections and rejections.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. There is at least one very similar question to this you might want to look at. https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/20470/abandoned-patents.

Comment: Even if possible, it probably belongs to your old  employer, not you.